# How to statically analyze a jar package(map-reduce application) and extract some features which affect execution time?

Tags: java, performance, hadoop, jar

What code features will affect the execution time of a program? Is there any way to statically analyze a jar package and extract these features? such as the count of logical operation, the count of arithmetic operation, the frequency of io operation, the depth of call stack, etc. I want to statically analyze a jar package of a map-reduce application and extract some useful code features that will affect the execution time. I can un-jar the package into .class files, or maybe decompile the .class file to java code,but different map-reduce application has different operations, how to analyze these files to get the features I want? If I want to know the count of loop in the code, do I need to analyze how many lines of a split data file that need to be processed by hadoop?

Answer (score 0):

It's basically impossible. The execution time of a program depends not on the number of loops (or I/O, or arithmetic operations, or anything else) in its code, but on the number of times that each of those operations will be executed. In any reasonable program, this will depend on the input data, and you can't say anything without access to input data.

(If you do have input data, you can simply run the program under a profiler and see which parts of it took the most time.)